# Visual Studio Windows Forms application - cache form input

Tags: c#

I have an application with one form and two dozen input fields, mostly text boxes, but also some checkboxes. I would like to keep the last input between two runs of the application on the same system, just for convenience - no 100% safety required.

Which is the easiest way to do so? I could of course write a wrapper that puts everything into a file in my self-designed format, but perhaps there is a built-in "cache" mechanism or something like that, which auto-generates XML or puts everything into the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my old [blog post](http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2009/08/save-winform-control-values-between.html) on the subject.  Basically each control has a PropertyBinding which can be saved on close and reloaded on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ObjectCache.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx

Or this recommended link: http://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/caching-in-a-desktop-application-using-objectcache-and-localdb/
http://www.splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/